# ¿Cómo crear un precio de apertura y cierre a partir del precio diario?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo una dataframe con precios de acciones de Gucci al dia y quiero obtener las precios de apertura y de cerrada del mercado.

```
# Lectura de datos
url = 'https://finance.services.appex.bing.com/Market.svc/ChartAndQuotes?symbols=160.1.KER.PAR&chartType=5y'
resp = requests.get(url=url)
prices_gucci = resp.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(prices_gucci[0]['Chart']['Series'])

# Corregir origen de timestamps
origen = df.loc[0, "T"]
df.loc[1:, "T"] = df.loc[1:, "T"] + origen

# Convertir a datetime
df["fecha"] = pd.to_datetime(df["T"], unit="m", origin=pd.Timestamp('2000-01-01'))

print(df.head())
    fecha       P
0   2014-01-31  148.05
1   2014-02-07  147.50
2   2014-02-14  152.30
3   2014-02-21  151.45
4   2014-02-28  148.60
```

En efecto como puedo hacer para obtener un dataframe como la siguiente :

```
        Date  Open   Close
0 2010-06-29  19.00  17.54  
1 2010-06-30  25.79  23.30  
2 2010-07-01  25.00  20.27  
3 2010-07-02  23.00  18.71  
4 2010-07-06  20.00  15.83
```

Pensé que tomaría el precio del día anterior como el precio de apertura y el precio dado para el precio de cierre. A menos que vayas por mejores ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu idea se puede implementar así:

```
# Nos aseguramos de que el dataframe este ordenado
dfs = df.sort_values(by=['T'])[['fecha', 'P']]
# Creamos una nueva columna con la cotización anterior
dfs['open'] = dfs.P.shift(1)
# Reordenamos y renombramos columnas
dfs = dfs[['fecha', 'open', 'P']].rename(columns={'P': 'close'})

print(dfs.head())

       fecha    open   close
0 2014-01-31     NaN  148.05
1 2014-02-07  148.05  147.50
2 2014-02-14  147.50  152.30
3 2014-02-21  152.30  151.45
4 2014-02-28  151.45  148.60
```

Lo fundamental aquí, es contar con los datos ordenados por fecha o timestamp, luego con [`shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html#pandas-dataframe-shift), desplazamos la columna 1 fila, y la incorporamos como la cotización de apertura, obviamente la primer fila no tendrá cotización de apertura.